# Audio element volume not resetting after setInterval with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, setinterval

The code below randomly selects and plays audio elements (of different pitches, chosen by the user). I am working on a fade option; the user specifies a fade-time in seconds, which is passed in by ID (`fade.value`).

I am actually having two problems:
A) In the first iteration, the audio elements begins fading before it starts playing.
B) When the same element is called repeatedly, if the fade time is longer than the repeat time, the volume does not reset properly (which was the intended point of `tone.volume=1`), but "stays down."

```
function pickAndPlay(pitchSet, saturation){
    var pitchCheck = rand(1,100);
    if (pitchCheck <= saturation){
        fyshuffle (pitchSet); // the Fischer-Yates shuffle
        var tone = document.getElementById(pitchSet[0]);
        tone.currentTime = 0;
        tone.volume = 1;
        tone.play();
        if(fadeTime.value>0){
            $(tone).animate({volume: 0}, fadeTime.value*1000);

        };
        document.getElementById("noteName").value=pitchSet[0];
        console.log(iteration);
        iteration++;
        console.log("tone.volume:"+tone.volume);
    };
};
function nextThing(millis,pitchSet,saturation){  
    if(iteration==0){pickAndPlay(pitchSet,saturation)};
    return setInterval(pickAndPlay,millis,pitchSet,saturation);  // this needs `return`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609995/settimeout-recursion-javascript
};
```

Thanks for any suggestions or references you can offer about how to fix these problems.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, the animation is still running when the audio begins playing again. Just use the jQuery `stop` method:

```
function pickAndPlay(pitchSet, saturation){
    var pitchCheck = rand(1,100);
    if (pitchCheck <= saturation){
        fyshuffle (pitchSet);
        var tone = document.getElementById(pitchSet[0]);
        tone.currentTime = 0;
        $(tone).stop();
        tone.volume = 1;
        tone.play();
        if(fadeTime.value>0){
            $(tone).animate({volume: 0}, fadeTime.value*1000); console.log(fadeTime.value);
        };
        document.getElementById("noteName").value=pitchSet[0];
        iteration++;
    };
};
```